# NodeJs Error: Cannot find module 'ncp'

Tags: node.js, cordova, mobile

Error:

> NodeJS build failed when calling require('ncp') OS: macOS High Sierra
>   10.13.2: 
>       module.js:472
>       throw err;
>       ^ Error: Cannot find module 'ncp'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/Users/Shared/WebServer/Mobile/builds/build.nodejs:28:21)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)

Code:

```
Require('ncp')
```

Please note all the paths and other details below:

- `ANDROID_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables contain the correct values. `bash_profile` has `ANDROID_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`.
- NPM and NCP installed globally using sudo.
- Given read and write access manually to `usr/local/lib` folder and all the child folders too. And tried with this commands also:

  ```
  chown -R 777 and chown -R 755
  ```
- Cordova version `5.4.1` (also tried with `7.0.1`).
- Node.js: `v7.10.1` (also tried with `v8.9.4` and `v4.3.1`).
- NPM version: `4.2.0`.
- JAVA SDK Version `9.0.18`.
- Android SDK :   Android SDK Platform Tools: `27.0.1`, Android SDK Tools: `26.1.1`

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: What are you working on? is it a cordova app? How is it related to `node.js` and `require`? what did you do that caused this error to appear?

Comment: I am having Cordova mobile app and build this app using node.js. When i run the node.js build script its failing.    "node build.nodejs MyApp_5.4.1.android.osx.json DEV build -w" is the build command.

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you build using 'cordova build android' or so?